# tough-cookie setCookie what is the currentDomain parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

This is an example of how to use tough-cookie `setCookie` (https://github.com/goinstant/tough-cookie):

`cookiejar.setCookie(cookie, 'http://currentdomain.example.com/path', cb);`

What is the second parameter actually supposed to be? Is it the `Path:` part of the cookie? Should I remove `Path:` from `cookie`?

Comment: I don't know exactly why but most node modules are terribly documented and/or explained, even the very famous ones. I'd be happy with just a bit of commenting within the code, here and there.

Comment: Hi, Did you find an answer to this?